# Issue creating excel formula in powershell

Tags: powershell

Below is the formula i am trying to work on

```
=HYPERLINK("#10.124.0.0_27!A2","10.124.0.0_27")
```

trying with the below code

```
$final_data ="=HYPERLINK(`"#" + $data + "!A" +$count + "," + "$data" + ")"
```

but getting output like

```
=HYPERLINK("#10.124.0.0_27!A2,10.124.0.0_27)
```

Not able to put the double quotes.
Please help me into this

Comment: `""","""` and `""")"` should fix that.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician. Can you post as answer so it may be helpful for other

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using below

```
"=HYPERLINK(`"#" + $data + "!A" +$count + """"+ "," + """" + "$data" + """)"
```

Thanks @TheMadTechnician

Answer (score 0):

You just need to properly escape your double quotes where needed. Since you are using double quotes your variables will expand just fine, you can just include them in the string. You can do that a couple ways, here's what I would do:

```
$final_data ="=HYPERLINK(""#$data!A$count"",""$data"")"
```

or

```
$final_data ="=HYPERLINK(`"#$data!A$count`",`"$data`")"
```